# WooCommerce wc_add_notice() with custom notice_type and cart update

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce, customization, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a notice type to the WooCommerce [`wc_add_notice()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_add_notice.html#67-90) types set (`success`, `notice`, `error`). Call it `'warning'`, it should be "more serious" than `'notice'` but less serous than `'error'` for the user.

I started copying `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/teplates/notices/notice.php` into `wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/notices/warning.php`.

Then i modified its class name to `woocommerce-warning`:

```
<?php foreach ( $messages as $message ) : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-warning"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $message ); ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then, to make it work, i had to add this code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_notice_types', function ($notice_types) {
    $notice_types[] =   "warning";
    return $notice_types;
});
```

to my `functions.php` to make WooCommerce print my new notice type.

Then of course some CSS to adjust colors and styles:

```
.woocommerce-warning {
    border-top-color:gold;
    border-bottom-color:gold;
}
.woocommerce-warning::before {
    content: "\e016";
    color: gold;
    top: 0.2em;
    left: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

Now, with a simple `wc_add_notice('message', 'warning');` my warning message is there!

Initially it seemed to work, but now i realize that it's behaving not the same as the original notice types: if i update the cart, i.e to correct products quantities (i think it's an AJAX call, may some jquery be there..?), my validator function adds a warning notice that doesn't get updated (it simply remains there with the old message). Replacing type `warning` to `notice` the message is updated as expected.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_check_cart_items', function() {
    $prod = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    wc_add_notice('Notice: cart containing '.$prod.' products', 'notice');      // message gets updated
    wc_add_notice('Warnign: cart containing '.$prod.' products', 'warning');    // this doesn't
});
```

Any ideas why?
My guess: maybe some jquery to work out...?

Thanx.

Comment: Do you want to hide `Notice` whenever there is a `Warning` message? and isn't this `woocommerce_check_cart_items` function adding both notice and warning?

Comment: @RaunakGupta First time in the cart page: both are printed. Then if i update quantities: notice message is updated, warning message is not. I want to: 1. remove the old warning message 2. display the new one, exactly like the notice messages do

Answer (score 0):

add error or success notice class with your custom class like this:  “woocommerce-message woocommerce-warning”

to make the js for it work and disappear
then for the css :

```
   .woocommerce-message.woocommerce-warning {
    border-top-color:gold;
    border-bottom-color:gold;
  }
    .woocommerce-message.woocommerce-warning::before  {
 content: "\e016";
color: gold;
top: 0.2em;
left: 0.5em;
font-size: 1.8em;
  }
```